# In a trigger accessing data from a different Object

Tags: apex, trigger

Im not sure that the trigger has much to do with the problem but it may. I am unable to get the value of a field even though it is in the custom Object. I am showing one section of which there are several. I leave out the others because they don't add to the question.

```
trigger ChangeAssignedRoom on lutd_Registration__c (after update) {

Id oldRoomId = null;
Id newRoomId = null;
Integer oldRoomOccQty = 0;
Integer newRoomOccQty = 0;
Integer newRoomCapacity = 0;
Integer oldRoomCapacity = 0;

System.debug('====>>>> if Trigger.isUpdate <<<<====');
if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
    System.debug('Count; ' + Trigger.new.size() );
    for(lutd_Registration__c newRecord : Trigger.new){  
        lutd_Registration__c oldRecord = Trigger.oldMap.get(newRecord.Id); 
        System.debug('Setup data ' );
        newRoomId    = newRecord.Assigned_Room__c;
        oldRoomId    = oldRecord.Assigned_Room__c;
        System.debug('New ' + newRoomId);
        System.debug('Old ' + oldRoomId);
        if( ! ( oldRoomId == newRoomId ) ) { 
            System.debug('Room Change');

            if (oldRoomId == null) { // update newroom;
                System.debug('Assign New Room, += 1 ' );
                sObject newRoom = newRoomId.getSObjectType().newSObject(newRoomId);
                if (newRoom.isSet('Occupied_Qty__c')) {
                    newRoomOccQty = Integer.valueOf(newRoom.get('Occupied_Qty__c'));
                    System.debug('After value Of: ' + newRoomOccQty );
                } 
                if (newRoomOccQty == null ) {
                    newRoomOccQty = 0;

                }
                System.debug('Before Increment: ' + newRoomOccQty );
                newRoomOccQty += 1;
                System.debug('After Increment:  ' + newRoomOccQty );
                newRoom.put('Occupied_Qty__c',newRoomOccQty );                    newRoomCapacity = Integer.valueOf(newRoom.get('Capacity__c'));
                if (newRoomCapacity == null || ! (newRoom.isSet('Capacity__c'))) {
                    newRoomCapacity = 0;
                } 
                if (newRoomOccQty >= newRoomCapacity ) {
                    newroom.put('Occupied__c', true ) ;
                } else {
                    newroom.put('Occupied__c', false ) ;
                }

                try {
                    update newRoom;
                } catch (DmlException e) {
                    // Process exception here
                }
             }
        } else {
            System.debug('Rooms are the same, NO Update');
        }
     } 
  } else {
    System.debug('Not Update');
  }
}
```

The value `newRoomOccQty` is not set by this line `newRoomOccQty = Integer.valueOf(newRoom.get('Occupied_Qty__c'));`.

While this does not error it also doe not get the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it fails is shown below in the comments:

```
// This line creates a new SObject with no fields populated except ID
sObject newRoom = newRoomId.getSObjectType().newSObject(newRoomId);

// this if statement fails because the sobject newRoom is not populated 
// with Occupied_Qty__c aforehand via an assignment or query 
if (newRoom.isSet('Occupied_Qty__c')) {
    newRoomOccQty = 
        Integer.valueOf(newRoom.get('Occupied_Qty__c'));
```

[Apex reference on sobject method isSet(xx)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm?search_text=sobject%20methods)

Comment: Is this the wrong method to get the Room Object and all the fields with the ID of newRoomId? 
Do I need a newRoom = rooms__c[] [SELECT Name, Id, Occupied_Qty__c, Capacity__c WHERE Id = : newRoomId ]

Comment: yep --- you need to query -- but you'll want to bulkify this since this is within a trigger (don't do SOQL in for loops). Consult Trailhead for tips on bulkification (or apex doc)

Comment: Used SOQL and bulkified. I used a Map with the room Object so I could get all my values. Looks simple now that I've worked thru it.